# The meaning of the phrase "Let me do the car door"

Tags: meaning

This is an example sentence for "close (verb)" in Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English.

> Let me do the car door – it won’t close properly.

What is the meaning of "Let me do the car door"?

Comment: By definition of [***do***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/do):
>1) to perform or complete (a deed or action)"   ⇒   *to do a portrait", "   ⇒   the work is done*". The action on the car door, in context is to close it. Consider that you could also say "Let me do *that* - it won’t close properly." which would mean the same thing.

Comment: Let me close it for you.

Answer (score 3):

Here the context of usage is important.

Lets see the following examples:

1. Suppose your intention is to help someone who is going to close/open
   the door, then "Let me do the car door" is more of a courtesy shown
   to help them out with the problematic door.
2. Another scenario is when you are determined to fix that problematic
   car door."Let me do the car door" here suggests that you are
   irritated with the problem and you want to fix it rightaway.

Comment: Great point. As a footnote: there are a number of factors involved, but I might pronounce the sentence slightly differently in the second scenario than I would in the first. In the first, I might emphasize *me* – particularly if the other person has been trying to close the door unsuccessfully: _Here, let **me** do the car door_. In the second scenario, I'm more likely to state it as if it were part of a to-do list: _Let me do the car door, and after that I'll feed the cat._

Answer (score 1):

Yes, without the context, it's not *absolutely* clear. But then, there's a hint that the door does not *shut* properly.

Building a context around what we are provided with, *"Let me do the car door..."* means *"Let **me close the door**"*. Say, your kid has sit inside the car. Knowing that the car door won't shut properly unless you apply some force, you may tell your kid, *"Hey, don't do that. Let me do the car door - it won't close properly (if you do it with no force).*